# Xulrunner runs but does nothing

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I am at my wits end. I've written a xul app and it runs fine if I open the .xul in firefox directly. But xulrunner doesn't cooperate at all. I can run my xul fine by using the -chrome flag for firefox and giving it an absolute path, but -app doesn't work on firefox either. I have all the files required (application.ini, chrome.manifest both in root and /chrome/ and tried with either missing as well) and their format has been checked and re-checked.

I was prepared to paste all my files here and link the code, but I've tried everything, including a boilerplate project from http://www.mozdev.org/projects/wizard/ (from the application wizard) which reacts the same way as my own project.

xulrunner returns no error message, nothing - it just stays there in the task manager, no cpu load, not loading anything to memory, inert.

I've tried other projects (https://github.com/matthewkastor/XULRunner-Examples - the periodic table works at least) but I can't get a single solid lead on why some projects run properly, while others just have xulrunner waiting and doing nothing. It also seems this is a rare problem because most people can at least run the boilerplate fine, even if their own projects don't initially run.

I don't think it's necessary to post my code at the moment since it behaves the same way as the boilerplate. Can anyone tell me possible reasons why xulrunner won't work with the boilerplate but will with the example project?

I'm running v25 on win xp sp2 and I have been searching and reading all day, so I'm pretty sure I've read everything related - thanks in advance; I hope 5 days of work won't be wasted :(

**edit:**

**SOLUTION: I messed up and didn't notice that prefs.js was missing or empty. Even if you have no preferences in your app, prefs.js is needed to set up the environment and tell firefox or xulrunner where the xul file to start from is. Without this pointer it has no idea. Yes, the MDN article does state this and what it contains is accurate, this was a big mistake on my part, as it seems I subconsciously (or not?) ignored the prefs.js file because I had no need for preferences in my app.
tl;dr if your apps don't work but the example files do, check your prefs.js even if you don't use preferences.**

Comment: Does it run with `firefox -app` ? Is XULRunner even being maintained anymore?!?

Comment: No, the -app option doesn't work either as I mention in the first paragraph. XULRunner is being maintained as far as I know and like, a day after I posted this, ff 26 was released and xulrunner was updated with it so it seems to be alive. edit - forgot to mention that v26 of xulrunner doesn't work either. I'm planning to clear ff and reinstall from scratch since i've had it installed for ages now and the profiles etc. could be overbloated, but it's going to be a very long and time consuming process so I've had to postpone it for other work.

Comment: mozdev.org is down.... can't use wizard... I'll find an app I built since all the changes in the FF "teens" and see if it runs against FF26.

Comment: mozdev is still down. I've uploaded the output of the wizard and the other test apps here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19805855605974540350 - myapp and glyphmancer are the important ones. thanks for the help :) and sorry for the delayed reply.

Comment: I the examples work for me when invoked via `firefox -app application.ini`. However your `myapp` bundle doesn't contain `chrome.manifest` at the top-level folder. Are you working from an old guide? Since XULRunner 2.0, applications follow the structure as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner (step #3 shows the layout). `chrome/chrome.manifest` doesn't actually get looked at anymore; however, you can include it from the top-level manifest if you wish.

Comment: `glyphmancer` also has the old app bundle structure.

Comment: When I first tried to bundle the app for xulrunner, I followed the MDN article pretty much blindly - when that didn't work, I started using whatever info I could find. That's probably why it doesn't make sense internally. myapp was generated by the wizard, iirc, as well as glyphmancer, which was the intended base for the actual app.

Comment: I've tried every combination and placement of chrome.manifests i could think of.  It seems more information is required - i'll try to rerun everything with xulrunner, firefox -app and firefox -chrome and i'll be back with a chart. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Try to copy the layout of the example files. They work for me in Firefox 20, 22, 23 and 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting this to close this question, since it doesn't need further answering.*

The fault was with me - the app required a valid `prefs.js` file which I hadn't created because I was under the impression it wasn't required unless you intended to have preferences in your app. The MDN (at least at the time) specified this.